# factory girl, association in default trait, but leave it unassociated when trait is passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm testing with rspec a `Company` model that has several `Addresses`.

I'm using factory girl to produce my test environment, I would like the default Company to have a few addresses registered, while I would like to have a trait for a specific case of a Company without any `Address`.

Here's what I'm doing now in the factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "company #{n}" }
    description     { "description #{name}" }

    trait :no_address do 
      addresses nil
    end

    after(:create) do |company, evaluator|
      create_list(:address, 3, company: company)
    end
  end
end
```

how can I make the factory so that when I use the trait `no_address` the addresses are not created at all?

thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FactoryGirl's [transient attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes) might be just what you need:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    transient do
      create_address true
    end

    sequence(:name) { |n| "company #{n}" }
    description     { "description #{name}" }

    trait :no_address do
      transient do 
        create_address false
      end
    end

    after(:create) do |company, evaluator|
      create_list(:address, 3, company: company) if evaluator.create_address
    end
  end
end
```